# How to upgrade Ubuntu 22.04 to 23.04

Tags: upgrade, 22.04

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04. How would I install Ubuntu 23.04 beta?

Comment: If you have to ask this here, I'd recommend to avoid using a development version of Ubuntu. Since you can not skip releases there is no supported upgrade path and you'd have to make a fresh install. Please remind that questions regarding development versions of Ubuntu are off-topic here.

Comment: wait for it to get released and then you will be able to ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ubuntu 23.04 (featuring GNOME 44 and Linux kernel 6.2) is set to release on April 20

Installing it now over a previous distribution is not recommended. Anyway, you will still be able to experiment it using VMs.

To the answer,

As @Rishon_JR said, you need to set `Prompt=normal` by doing

```
sudo nano /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
```

I tried installing Ubuntu 23.04 in my Virtual machine with Ubuntu 22.10 using `sudo do-release-upgrade -d`  and it didn't work.

However, if you really want to install it on your primary system(not recommended). You can follow the steps

→ Update your system, `sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade`

→ Run the following command to add the lunar repository

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lunar main restricted universe multiverse"
```

→ Once again, run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`. It will download all necessary files and install Ubuntu 23.04 with Linux kernel 6.1.0.

→ Reboot

The above steps should work.

- Remember, it is not a stable version, and you may try it out in a virtual machine or wait till its official release.

After using it for a few hours, it is not that bad, apart from some bugs like nautilus crashing when I try to search something.

Comment: So it was released today, yet `$ sudo do-release-upgrade` tells me *"There is no development version of an LTS available."*

Comment: It takes time for it to take effect.

Comment: That add-apt-repository lunar is a bad idea. It just force enables the updated versions and bypasses any migration scripts

Answer (score 5):

You can upgrade by doing `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` or visiting their daily builds website [here](https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/), creating a Live USB and while selecting on how to install ubuntu, you have the "Upgrade Ubuntu" option (Or reinstall if you wish). Note that it is possibly unstable and trying it on a VM first is recommended. I wouldn't recommend installing it on your main computer.

EDIT: You have to set `Prompt=normal` in `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` when using the `do-release-command` when upgrading to a non-LTS release. Do `sudo /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades`, change `Prompt=lts` to `Prompt=normal` and save